# How to find if my data are from poisson distribution

Tags: r, testing, distribution, poisson

I want to ask what ways are useful for finding distribution of my data.
My data looks like :   City - count of votes for president in the election in this town.

I´m using R studio for my work and I don´t know, how to find if my data are from Poisson distribution.

Thanks for help

Comment: It is always good practice to add [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This will attract people more to think about your problem. But als have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31741742/how-to-identify-the-distribution-of-the-given-data-using-r) where you might find an answer.

Comment: http://www.di.fc.ul.pt/~jpn/r/distributions/fitting.html this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

For Poisson distribution mean is equal to variance. Compute mean and variance of your data and see if they're close

Example

```
q <- rpois(10000, 3.3)
mean(q)
```

output

```
[1] 3.2973

sd(q)^2

[1] 3.225435

var(q)

[1] 3.225435
```

Close enough?

After that you could use some standard test like [Kolmogorov-Smirnov](http://sherrytowers.com/2018/04/09/kolmogorov-smirnov-test/)

Comment: I don't think that this is the right way to detect the distribution shape. Consider you have a data set like this `set.seed(12)`  , `data <- cos(runif(1000,-10,10) * sin( rnorm(1000,4,2)))`.  We can normalize the data like this `data = 2*(data - mean(data))/sd(data) + 4`  . After getting our new data if we call `mean(data)` and `var(data)` ,  not surprisingly we get **4**. So the mean and the variance of the data is exactly the same. But is it a poisson distiribution? `hist(data,40)` tells no.

Comment: @maydin Nevertheless, that is where I would start - it is very simple check and if mean differs from variance - you don't have Poisson, no need to run other tests

Comment: For a starting purpose. You are totaly right!  I just misunderstood.